# Will a Reply-All email thread with 20 participants improve our email reputations?

Tags: email

1 person will send an email to 20 participants. Each participant will reply-all to the message - and continue to do so for each response they receive.

Will this improve our email reputations? What about our email reputations with gmail users / outlook users? (assuming that some of the 20 participants are gmail or outlook users)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the content of your email, not how many are sent or how many replies there are.

According to this http://www.towerdata.com/blog/bid/116384/Email-Reputation-What-It-s-All-About which I found by doing a search for *what is email reputation* (wink);

> There are three principal components of email reputation:
>
> - Bounce rate:
>     The number of messages that are returned as undeliverable divided by
>     the number of emails sent
> - Complaint rate: The number of people who
>     report your messages as spam divided by the number of emails delivered
> - Spam trap hits: The number of messages delivered to addresses that are
>     explicitly used to trace and catalog spam

It should be added that 20 emails is a trivial number to send on the scale of how many emails are sent in a typical campaign.

Comment: "Each participant will reply-all to the message" - 400 emails. "and continue to do so" - ???

Comment: @DocRoot it is only 20 emails from each participant, what they do or don't do won't contribute to the OPs reputation